# @ symbol appearing n Excel formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula, symbols

I have many excel workbooks all linked together via formula. Recently I've noticed the @ symbol appearing before the functions. For Example @if(, @index(, @Match(, @hlookup(

It seems benign and i can get rid of it via a find and replace. But i'm keen to know why it is there.

None of the source data has been converted into a table and i can't find anything via google.

[Update - A colleague has since had the attached message pop up:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9S3Mg.png)

Comment: Your Excel version probably now got access to the new dynamic array functions.

Comment: Thanks JvdV i wasn't aware of the new functions so will explore them,

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic as it's about Excel functionality.

Comment: Excel 365 (2019) automatically inserts '@' on all positions, where arrays may occur. This happens to be internal Functions like INDEX but also User Defined Functions. It does this even with old XLS-Files, wich leads to compatibility problems when reopening them. REMOVE the @. The functions worked before and will work in future - still without @! This is a very confusing automatism!